# Passing JSON Array to view

Tags: spring

How do I list out the values in View from the values in JSON Array that I got from requesting API? I am using spring mvc and thymeleaf

Answer (score 1):

You can use annotation @RequestBody to get your jsonArray and using a wrapper which has a model list store your list.
like following:

Model:

```
public class Tuple {
private String key;
private String value;
private String description;
public String getKey() {
    return key;
}
public void setKey(String key) {
    this.key = key;
}
public String getValue() {
    return value;
}
public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Tuple(String key, String value, String description) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
    this.description = description;
}
```

}

Wrapper:

```
public class TupleWrapper{
    private List<Tuple> tupleList;
    public List<Tuple> getTuple() {
        return tupleList;
    }
    public void setTuple(List<Tuple> tuples){
        this.tupleList = tuples;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/setTuple", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus> setTuple(@RequestBody TupleWrapper wrapper){
    //your logic.
    return new ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus>(new ResponseStatus<>(STATUS.SUCCESS,"OK",wrapper),HttpStatus.OK);

}
```